# How to enable the download window prompt for javascript-based Selenium-webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am using 'selenium-webdriver' npm package to simulate an endpoint user - I click on buttons, select drop-downs and checkboxes.

I come across an image that will help me download a PDF file.

- So what I want and what happens when I manually click on this image button on a regular chrome tab is that it will prompt a save-window:

[image]

- What actually happens is that the file is downloaded automatically in the default directory (which is 'download' folder for me), without showing the save-window prompt. If the same file is already present in the download folder, then the new file gets a suffix of "(2)" or a corresponding number to its name.

I generally use this basic Selenium documentation: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started_with_webdriver/browsers/

2nd reference I use is: [Selenium-javascript-docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Options.html)

Most of the Selenium question-answers are in the java language, so those don't help me as I'm using the javascript package.

I do know it has to do with the chrome options, or a chrome-specific field, but the document is just lacking. I came across the [chrome-driver doc](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities), but it is not javascript-friendly.

Other than disabling the automatic-download feature, I am also interested in changing the download directory to a custom location.

Any help or reference/guide/documentation source is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance and thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setDownloadPath](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Driver.html#setDownloadPath) to modify the path where the file will be downloaded.

Other than that, I don't think there's an option to prevent the automatic download

Comment: Thank you. I had the same documentation open but missed this. This is a good alternative and I can use this. 
I am still waiting for the original solution, since I have seen the solution implemented via java language.

Comment: This was easy to implement. I have achieved my purpose with this solution. The wait for original solution is just my curiosity. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help!